# Keep last position of animated View while presenting a VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewanimation

I'm animating a ImageView to move it up. Everything works fine, but when I present a ViewController the ImageView swaps back to its original position.

I tried already to set the Frame when the Animation is completed, But it still swap back to its original position.

heres what I do:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidLoad:animated];
    [self performSelector:@selector(animationCode) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

//Animate welcome screen
-(void)animationCode{
    CGRect imageFrame = self.imageViewLogo.frame;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        self.imageViewLogo.center = CGPointMake(self.imageViewLogo.center.x, self.imageViewLogo.center.y-150);
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        self.imageViewLogo.frame = CGRectMake(imageFrame.origin.x, imageFrame.origin.y-150, imageFrame.size.width, imageFrame.size.height);
    }];
}
```

Any idea how to fix this? I think it has something todo with the viewDissapering..

Comment: Are there autolayouts enabled?

Comment: yes, and I need it :S

Comment: You should not set any frames when using auto layout -- when the view needs to be redrawn, the subviews will revert to the positions defined by their constraints, not the new frames you've assigned. You need to do any moving or resizing by modifying constraints instead.

Comment: One thing I notice is starting the animation in viewDidLoad instead of in viewDidAppear.  I'm also not sure why you're repositioning it again in the completion block.

Comment: @rdelmar damn it, how should I do that?

Comment: @David I tried also without the line in the completion block.. doesn't help..

Comment: @SaifDeen See my answer on how to animate using constraint modification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should not animated views in `viewDidLoad`. You should start animation in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`.

What was said in the comments is correct, you should not be modifying frames directly when autolayout is enabled. Any constraint update or layout pass that comes will reset the frames to their original values. What you should do is modify the constraints themselves that are in place. If you add these constraints in code, perhaps save the ones necessary for animation as properties and modify them in the animation setup method. If you set up your view in Interface Builder, you can create outlets of constraints in the code and access them that way. Remember to call `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` inside your animation block to actually trigger a constraint update and layout pass.

```
-(void)animationCode{
    CGRect imageFrame = self.imageViewLogo.frame;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        self.imageViewLogoYConstraint.constant -= 150;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Where, `imageViewLogoYConstraint` is a constraint example that has been set up somewhere.

Comment: I checked again my view in the IB. I didnt set any constraints on the Imageview..

Comment: @SaifDeen If you do not add constraints in Interface Builder, default constraints are added for you. These default constraints are meant to keep it in place, where it has been put in IB. You need to add constraints because you cannot link these default ones to an outlet.

Comment: I tried to add a Y constraint, but I can't find the right alignment constraint in IB...

Comment: @SaifDeen You cannot add only Y constraint, you need to add all constrains so layout is not ambiguous.

Comment: damn, ty it worked! For everyone has the same problem: Add all constraints, add a outlet for the Y achse constraint and modify it like leo wrote. Thanks again!

Comment: @SaifDeen Good to hear! :D